# YII2 UrlManager и относиетльные ссылки в консольном приложении

Tags: yii2

Можно ли в консольном приложении YII2 получить относительные ссылки через UrlManager? UrlManager требует определить baseUrl у себя и это приходится сделать, однако мне нужно получить относительные ссылки когда вызываю Url::to(['site/index']).

В web приложении относительные ссылки получаются вот так Url::to(['site/index']). А абсолютные Url::to(['/site/index']), однако в консоли это не работает.

Comment: позвольте узнать, зачем вам в консольном приложении ссылки ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, документацию внимательнее прочитал. Нужно описывать домен в hostInfo, у меня компонент был неправильно сконфигурирован, вместо этого я описал домен в baseUrl.

А ссылки абсолютные в консольном приложении делаются, например так

```
Url::to(['site/index'], true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Что бы не копировать весь код, вот ссылка на подробное описание решения вашей проблемы
[Url manager for console](https://ignitevision.bg/blog/2016/06/27/yii2-urlmanager-create-valid-link-from-console-app/)

Comment: Там оно не такое большое, поэтому можно и скопировать с указанием на источник. Тем более ссылка может завтра помереть и все с аналогичной проблемой окажутся без решения